# How to subscribe inside a WebFlux Controller

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, webflux

Inside a REST controller, I need to call a REST to obtain a value to be used as a URI variable to a second REST call.

```
@PostMapping
public void abbina(@RequestBody DocumentsUploadRequest documentsUploadRequest) {

  Mono<GetResult> result = WebClient
      .create(url)
      .get()
       .....
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(GetResult.class)
      ;

  WebClient.post()
      .uri(...)
      .path("/{partita}")
      .build(result.block().getValue()))
      .....
      .bodyToMono(PostResult.class)
   ....
}
```

The problem is that inside a WebFlux REST isn't possibile call block on a mono/flux.

The code throw

> java.lang.IllegalStateException block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are
> blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http

I tried to change

> .build(result.block().getValue()))

with

> .build(result.share().block().getValue()))

But now the problem is that `result.share().block()` hangs indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never block within a reactive pipeline. You should **subscribe** instead. In that particular case, the Spring Webflux framework will subscribe for you as long as you provide your publisher. To achieve this, the controller method has to return your `Mono` publisher like this:

```java
@PostMapping
public Mono<Void> abbina(@RequestBody Attribute documentsUploadRequest) {

}
```

Here, the `Mono<Void>` defines that your publisher will complete without any value.

Then you have to build a reactive pipeline without blocking.

The result of the first HTTP call is a `Mono` of `GetResult`:

```java
private Mono<GetResult> getResult() {
    return WebClient
            .get()
            //...
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(GetResult.class);
}
```

Similarly, the second HTTP call returns a `Mono` of `PostResult`:

```java
private Mono<PostResult> postResult(String firstResult) {
    return WebClient
            .post()
            //...
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(PostResult.class);
}
```

Finally, combine these two publisher in order to build your pipeline using the [`flatmap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operator:

```java
@PostMapping
public Mono<Void> abbina(@RequestBody Attribute documentsUploadRequest) {
    return getResult()
            .flatMap(result -> postResult(result.getValue()))
            .then();
}
```

I'd recommend taking a look at the following guide: [Building a Reactive RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)